# What if a granary is built in the same turn a city growths?

Tags: civilization-5

What if a granary is built in the same turn a city is growing?

Does the granary's bonus will take effect before the growth and save the food?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

In order, your city will first get the food, and create a new citizen if that's enough, then get the production, and then create the building.